# Multiple VLANs on a single port Virtual Host

Tags: switch, hp, dot1q

I have a physical host server connected to an HP (say, 2650 series?) switch. The host is running multiple Hyper-V virtualized OSes, each on a different VLAN. If I make the switch port dot1q tagged for each VLAN and untagged on the main host, will that allow access for the OSes to function and connect to the network?

In pseudo-Cisco terms, if I make it a trunk port for VLAN 2&3 and an access port for VLAN 1 (you can do that in HP), will this solve my problem?

This is very time sensitive so I'm sorry for the short post. More information is available to me if needed. Thanks!

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You say you are already running virtualized OSes on the host, which are running in different VLANs. Hence I guess you already have the switch configured to perform dot1q trunking (Cisco terminology), otherwise you would not be able to have different VLANs.

Regarding the main host, you can configure Hyper-V either to use a tagged VLAN or send the management traffic untagged. Compare [this answer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/bf5df8b5-30a4-41de-9470-a24aa4245b96/using-a-trunk-port-for-management-interface-and-other-vlans-in-hyperv-server-2012-bare-metal?forum=virtualmachingmgrhyperv) at Microsoft Technet.

If you configure the management VLAN to be tagged, there is no need to configure an untagged port at your Switch. Otherwise, you need to configure one untagged VLAN (HP), or native VLAN (Cisco terminology). You can set any existing VLAN to be sent untagged. In summary, the management packets are tagged anyway. Either to already tag them at the host, or the switch performs the tagging, as soon as the untagged packet coming in at native VLAN proceeds to another trunk, there this management VLAN needs to be tagged.